# Discrete PID controller Laplace formula

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I saw the following formula:

the transfer function is:
$$Gr(s) = K_p \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{T_n s}+ \frac{T_v s}{1 + T_d s}\bigg) $$
From my understanding:

- $K_p$ is the proportional gain
- $T_n$ is the integral gain
- $T_v$ is the derivative gain

What is $T_d$?

EDIT:

I found an explanation to the extra variable: the differential term includes a limiting low pass also. So now is $T_v$ the derivative gain and $T_d$ the low pass filter? And, what is the use of a filter on the derivative action?

Comment: could you explain more? where is this problem from?

Comment: This is a PID formula that I had laying around, and I can't find the source, this website http://lorien.ncl.ac.uk/ming/digicont/digimath/dpid1.htm explains how to obtain a discrete PID but again there's no Td term there

Comment: As far as I see Td is the derivative in time, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Alternative_nomenclature_and_PID_forms

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would be good if we had a standard reference, the one you gave is not working for me. Sorry, I must go for now, I'll be back in a while

Comment: But Td is in the denominator, isn't the Laplace of a derivative, s? So shouldn't Td (if Td is the derivative in time) be in the nominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator $1 + T_d s$ acts as a filter to prevent the D action from actually being a derivative. Pure derivatives are not physically implementable, because the gain would go to infinity at high frequencies. (Trace the Bode plot to verify!) The extra pole at $T_d$ limits the gain and allows the use of the D term in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you have a reference on how to tune this Td filter gain?

Comment: Rule of thumb: $T_d = N T_v$ with $N$ between 2 and 10. Reference: your favorite introductory controls textbook will probably explain more, and there are several texts focussed on PID control which will have more information than you need.