# Time domain response of this transfer function

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

Would like to determine the time domain equation for this  transfer function  H(s) = a s / ( (a/b) s + 1) ) = Y(s) / U(s).

This [answer on the Mathematics Stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358994/discrete-pid-controller-laplace-formula) discusses the same equation, but doesn't work through finding the time domain equation.  The question and answer describe that the transfer function corresponds to the derivative term of a PID controller and the denominator, (a/b) s + 1, implements a low pass filter to allow the derivative to be implemented for real systems.

Steps for computing the time domain response are given by  [this answer on the Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100772/back-from-transfer-function-s-domain-to-differential-equation-in-t-domain).   This answer describes replacing s with dy/dt, s^2 with d^2/dt^2, etc. Using those steps gives the result:

y'(t) =  b ( u'(t) - 1/a).

Having trouble understanding this result, because if u[t] is constant, then u'[t] is zero, and the above results gives y'[t] = -b/a, which suggest that y[t] is decreasing for all time.  I expected y[t] to be zero. Is my expectation wrong?  Or, perhaps, my calculation of the time domain expression is wrong.

To summarize my questions:

1. what is the time domain equivalent for the transfer function: H(s) = a s / ( (a/b) s + 1)
2. method(s) for computing this
3. for constant input, u(t) = constant, will y(t) be zero?

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function is $$Y(s) = \frac{a s}{cs+1}U(s),$$ where $c=\frac{a}{b}$, and we want to find a way to represent it in the time domain without involving the time derivative $\dot{u}(t)$, especially since $u(t)$ is not necessary differentiable.

Well, the first option is to rewrite the system as a state-space model, then the answer becomes evident. Another option is to rewrite is as
$$Y(s) = \frac{a}{c}\frac{cs+1-1}{cs+1}U(s) = \frac{a}{c}U(s) - \frac{a}{c} \frac{1}{cs+1}U(s),$$ and $y(t) = \frac{a}{c}u(t) - \frac{a}{c}z(t)$, where $$Z(s) = \frac{1}{cs+1}U(s).$$ The time-domain model for $z$ is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The following, taken from [here](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SDE.html), might be a satisfactory answer:

H(s) = Y(s) / U(s) =  a s / ( (a/b) s + 1)

Y(s) ( (a/b) s + 1) = U(s)  a s

changing to time domain and replacing Y(s) s by y'(t) and U(s) s by u'(t) gives:

(a/b) y'(t) + y(t) = a u'(t)

re-arranging to solve for y(t) give

y(t) = a (u'(t) - (1/b) y'(t) )

so the output of the transfer function in the time domain is a measure of the difference between the derivative of the input and the derivative of the output.